# String concatenation using pointers in C!

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote the following code for string concatnation using pointers in C

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void strCat(char *str1,char *str2);
int main(void)
{
char str1[] = "Rohit";
char str2[] = "Kumar";  
strCat(str1,str2);
return 0;
}

void strCat(char *str1,char *str2)
{
int i;
char *start;
start = str1;
printf("%s",str1);
while(*str1++ != '\0')
    continue;
while(*str2 != '\0')
    *str1++ = *str2++;
*str1 = '\0';

printf("%s\n",str1);
}
```

Why the ouput is `Rohit(null)`. Please Help!!

Comment: I  really hope you just did this to learn stuff and not for any real code (there are functions like `strcat`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first of all `str1` isn't long enough to fit both strings.

Here

```
while(*str2 != '\0')
    *str1++ = *str2++; /* You are overstepping str1 -> undefined behavior */
```

There are other problems with the code. Perhaps you should try the `string.h` `strcat` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the `str1` pointer, and setting it to "\0" at the end, and then printing NULL.  I think this is what  you need:

```
void strCat(char *str1,char *str2)
{
int i;
char *start;
printf("%s",str1);
while(*str1++ != '\0')
    continue;
start = str1;
while(*str2 != '\0')
    *str1++ = *str2++;
*str1 = '\0';

printf("%s\n",start);
}
```

Also, as someone else noted, str1 isn't big enough to hold both strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*str1++ != '\0')
    continue;
while(*str2 != '\0')
    *str1++ = *str2++;
```

In the first loop, you loop till `*str==0`. And when it finally happens, you still increment `str1` leaving the `'\0'` as it was.

This is more correct:

```
while(*str1++ != '\0');
--str1;
while(*str2 != '\0')
    *str1++ = *str2++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a dangerous thing. `str1` and `str2` are fixed-size arrays, and `str1` doesn't have enough space for the content you're copying into it. The result leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you are printing str1, it will have null value because you have incremented the str1 pointer till the end and stored the null value.

when you print str1, it is pointing to null hence printing null